# Get gcc to flush all open fstreams upon termination like C streams are

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream *file1 = new ofstream("file1.txt");
    (*file1) << "hi\n";
    FILE *file2 = fopen("file2.txt", "w");
    fprintf(file2, "hi\n");
    abort();
}
```

file1.txt is empty but file2.txt contains the text.

Is there any way to ensure all open fstreams are flushed upon program termination, without using `std::endl` or manual flushes after every write?

gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)

Comment: As part of C99's section on files, *Other paths to
program termination, such as calling the abort function, need not close all files
properly.* Your example would work better with `ofstream file1` and `exit()`. `exit` does not destroy objects with automatic storage duration, which means `file1`, but it does flush and close C streams.

Comment: Actually `printf()` does flush on '\n' so you get that text not because `FILE` streams flushed on abort()

Comment: @Slava, Only if the stream is line buffered.

Comment: @chris What if I use signal function and a signal handler that calls exit?

Comment: @NeilKirk why not to use `std::endl` instead?

Comment: @Slava Cos it's slow

Comment: @NeilKirk, From what I can tell, there would be no good way to call the destructors with using a signal handler.

Comment: Isn't gcc 4.1.2 7 years old?

Comment: @remyabel Dunno, if there is a solution for up to date version I could try that.

Comment: Kind of the whole point of using `abort()` is for debugging the failed program state. You want it to exit right there, right now, and drop a core file. Not after cleaning things up.

Comment: @ZanLynx I want it to flush all the log files before closing, if it can..

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, no legal way.

But in gcc 4.1 you may hack around with `__attribute__ ((destructor))`. This will require to make stream global and to use `exit (-1)` instead of `abort`

The whole story looks like:

```
ofstream *file1;

int __attribute__ ((constructor))
pre_exec_fn (void)
{
  file1 = new ofstream("file1.txt");
}

int __attribute__ ((destructor))
post_exec_fn (void)
{
  file1->flush();
  delete file1;
}

int main()
{
    (*file1) << "hi\n";
    exit(-1);
}
```

This solution is highly gcc-specific and not recomended in normal cases, but there was some times, it was helpful for me, specially for debugging, to ensure that program leaves any log.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a Linux or Posix point of view. If you want just strict language standard compliance (i.e. [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11)) you'll need to use constructors and destructors.

For example, you could use some smart pointer, i.e. use [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and declare:

```
 std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream> file1= new ofstream("file1.txt");
```

I strongly recommend using a newer version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), i.e. `g++` version 4.9.1. Your 4.1 version is very old and is not C++11 standard compliant.

From a Linux point of view, things are different if the program terminates with a signal (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html); notice that few functions can be legally called from signal handlers, and `exit` cannot, and some signals cannot be caught, and several signals terminate immediately the process if no explicit signal handler has been installed), thru [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) or by returning from `main` (where an *implicit* `exit` occurs).

You could also register with [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) -if you don't use any smart pointer- an exit handler function which would explicitly flush or close all streams that your program is explicitly keeping somewhere (you'll need to manage how and where). Notice that [abort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html)  does *not* use `exit` (or [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) syscall)

As [Konstantin Vladimirov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26354567/841108) answered you could also use GCC specific [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (e.g. `__attribute__((constructor))`)

Comment: Exhaustive answer! Thanks (upvoted). I didn't think about smart pointer usage here. Even in gcc 4.1 simple wrapper might be created for iostream.

But all this (including my answer) will work only when ``exit`` is used. Will glibc call ``unique_ptr`` destructor on ``abort``? My experiments shows, that it will not.